# Face Comparison and Recognition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In our graduation project we want to compare image to the images uploaded when creating a post for missing people and the images uploaded while creating the post are stored in Images folder in wwwroot we want to compare both images and retrieve post with image similar to the image uploaded.

is that possible to do with Asp.net Core 3.1
Any Links or other references could help us doing that.

Comment: Suggest you use third party library, e.g. https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/FaceRecognitionDotNet

Comment: i recommend deepface library for python - https://github.com/serengil/deepface . it has an api as well. you can interact with its api from your asp net application.